# C++ Memory Access Violation occurring with List only, not Vectors for Same Operations

Tags: c++, stl

I've been creating a C++ Vulkan Program which uses a Child-Parent class system for managing resources and freeing them in the correct order automatically. For example, consider the code below -

```cpp
/**
 * Forward declaration of parent class
 */
class ParentResource;

/**
 * Represents a single child resource, all child resources must inherit from this class
 */
class ChildResource {
protected:

    /**
     * Creates an uninitialized resource, if this constructor is used then
     * the init method MUST be called if the derived object is ever initialized
     */
    ChildResource() {}

    /**
     * Adds a child resource to the list of child resources to be managed
     * @param parent The parent resource managing this resource
     */
    ChildResource(ParentResource& parent) : parentPtr(&parent) {
        parent.resources.push_back(this);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a child resource to the list of child resources to be managed
     * @param parent The parent resource managing this resource
     */
    virtual void init(ParentResource& parent) {
        parentPtr = &parent;
        if (std::find(parent.resources.begin(), parent.resources.end(), this) == parent.resources.end())
            parent.resources.push_back(this);
    }

    /**
     * Removes the child resource from the list of child resources to be managed
     */
    ~ChildResource() {
        if (parentPtr == nullptr) return;
        ParentResource& parent = *parentPtr;
        parent.resources.erase(std::remove(parent.resources.begin(), parent.resources.end(), this),
            parent.resources.end());
    }

    /**
     * The pointer to the parent
     */
    ParentResource* parentPtr = nullptr;

    friend class ParentResource;

public:

    /**
     * Frees resources if not already freed
     */
    virtual void freeResources() {
        if (parentPtr == nullptr) return;
        ParentResource& parent = *parentPtr;
        parent.resources.erase(std::remove(parent.resources.begin(), parent.resources.end(), this),
            parent.resources.end());
    }
};
```

```cpp
/**
 * Forward declaration of child resource
 */
class ChildResource;

/**
 * Represents a single parent resource which manages several child resources
 */
class ParentResource {
protected:

    /**
     * All child resources being managed by this parent resource
     */
    std::vector<ChildResource*> resources;

    friend class ChildResource;
public:

    /**
     * Frees all children resources
     */
    virtual ~ParentResource() {
        freeResources();
    }

    /**
     * Frees all children resources
     */
    virtual void freeResources() {
        for (ChildResource* resource : resources) { // Memory Access Violation when using std::vector
            try {
                resource->freeResources();
            }
            catch (const std::exception& e) {
                console.error(e.what());
            }
        }
        resources.clear();
    }
};
```

This setup is used to free resources automatically that rely on certain vulkan objects, for example a Device class would inherit from the parent class and things which rely on the device (swapchain, graphics pipeline, shaders, etc) inherit from children with the parent set as the device.

Most of the above is just background only and this issue isn't really about Vulkan but more so the C++ `list` stl, hence why I didn't add the Vulkan tag. Where my issue arises is I keep getting a memory access violation within the destructor of the parent class.

Upon debugging I found that a nullptr was present within the list somehow, which perplexed me. What perplexed me more was when I added the following line the crash still continued -

```
if (resource == nullptr) continue;
```

Then upon changing the `Parent` class children list from a `std::list` to a `std::vector`, the code worked with no issues whatsoever.

I don't like the concept of using code which just "magically works" and failed to comprehend why this works and why the list didn't. I believe linked lists are a superior data structure for this specific case and would like to continue to use them.

Can someone please explain why the std::list causes a memory access violation and the std::vector does not? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I really wish that instead of all these paragraphs of description and pseudocode, that you simply show a minimal C++ code example.  It would be so much easier to identify what you're doing wrong.  I fear that your attempts to abstract the problem into this type of question are hiding the problem.  If you are unable to use a debugger or common debugging techniques to identify the problem on your own, then the last thing you should be doing is re-interpreting the problem.  You are struggling to understand memory problems, which can be devious to the uninitiated.  You should show a real example.

Comment: I was hoping that the pseudo code would be easier to read. I'll just post the real code instead since that's easier.

Comment: No, pseudocode is _not_ easier to read, except for people who don't know C++ maybe.  You are here to ask a C++ question, and we want to be able to read what's really going on in your program.  Don't assume that you know where the problem is happening.  Just because the crash is happening in the parent does not mean that the parent code is wrong.  It's equally likely the issue is somewhere else.  Provide a full example to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I'll definitely keep that in mind for the future, thanks for clarifying and apologies!

Comment: Should be all fixed now, apologies again! I'll avoid that in the future.

Comment: @KingCoder11 Try to make a [mre]. We can't copy and compile your code _as-is_ (even after the update) so we can't reproduce the access violation.

Comment: Parent loops through its container of child resources and calls a function on them which, in turn, access the same container in their own parent and clear it, and you are surprised it crashed with lists? The surprise is that it didn't crash with vectors :p

Comment: What exactly is the goal here? You talk about automatically freeing resources, but there are no `new`s or `delete`s in your code. If you want automatic cleanup, you should look at using smart pointers.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sorry about that, working on getting a full snippet which can compile now. @super Classes which inherit from the child override `freeResources()` and use the parent pointer (in my case holds a `vk::Device`) to destroy the held resources.

Comment: Andy Newman's comment looks spot-on.  `ChildResource::freeResources` modifies the container that `ParentResource::freeResources` is iterating over.  This is a giant no-no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TLDR - Lists don't support removing items during iterations but somehow vectors do?

As Andy Newman stated in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69802767/c-memory-access-violation-occurring-with-list-only-not-vectors-for-same-opera?noredirect=1#comment123385997_69802767) the issue was modifying the container while looping. I'm not sure why it compiled with `std::vector` at all but I was able to replicate the same behavior on MSVC (Original Post was using Apple Clang). The solution was to simply add a boolean argument to the `freeResources()` function which only the `freeResources()` of the parent class would set to false. This argument stops modifying of the list if set to false. Code example below -

```cpp
// Parent Class
virtual void freeResources() {
    for (ChildResource* resource : resources) { // Memory Access Violation when using std::vector
        try {
            resource->freeResources(false);
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e) {
            console.error(e.what());
        }
    }
    resources.clear();
}

// Child Class

/**
 * Frees resources if not already freed
 * @param remove Whether or not to remove this from the list
 */
virtual void freeResources(bool remove = true) {
    if (!remove || parentPtr == nullptr) return;
    parentPtr->resources.remove(this);
}
```

No Additional code was necessary to be shown, this may not have been a fully reproducible example which I apologize for (and will avoid in the future) but it was certainly enough to spot the problem as Andy Newman was capable of showing.

Thank you to everyone who attempted to help/took the time to read this!